# Webrtc android native error #AddStream is not available with Unified Plan SdpSemantics. Please use AddTrack instead

Tags: java, android

I am working on audio video calling application using
web-rtc  dependency
`implementation 'com.dafruits:webrtc:113.0.0'`
on these line

```
public void addLocalStream(MediaStream stream) {
//pc is for peerconnection
if (pc == null) return;
Log.d("dds_test", "addLocalStream");

          pc.addStream(stream);
    }
```

I am getting this error
E/rtc: #
# Fatal error in: ../../../home/rno/webrtc/src/pc/peer_connection.cc, line 827
# last system error: 0
# Check failed: !IsUnifiedPlan()
# AddStream is not available with Unified Plan SdpSemantics. Please use AddTrack instead.

I  searched  a lot but could not find any proper solution please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message already gives you the answer, please use addTrack() instead of addStream()

Comment: do you have any example code? that  uses addTrack()  instead of addStream().

Comment: @ZahidYameen You only need to change pc.addStream() to pc.addTrack(), and then check the source code for the parameters that addTrack() will take.